# IdentityServer4 ImplicitFlow Authentication Redirects to Self after Success

Tags: c#, identityserver4

The issue is that with the quickstart(with entity), I used my own database to authenticate the users and manage claims. I put a simple authetication method into the login model and called it in the login callback. It works and the user authenticates but never redirects to the main page it came from instead it goes back to the login page. Already logged in you can see the username and logout option in top left.

The application works with test users but not external.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please let me know if you need more info.

edit1: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Need to see your configuration. What you are probably missing is the redirectUrl.

Comment: But its in the model.ReturnUrl ? I will include what I can to help

Comment: No, i mean the configuration for identityserver4.

Comment: @12seconds more added

Comment: Where does `192.168.1.15:51849/auth` redirects to? Is that your callback to handle redirection?

Comment: yes that is javascript to handle the redirect and set cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it... It's caused by the extra code from the quickstart, that i actually highlighted addtestusers